# Comprobar si hay mayusculas o minúsculas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un programa que mira si una string tiene mayusculas o minúsculas:

```
import string 
numbers   = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
letters   = string.ascii_lowercase
letters   = letters.split()
word      = input("Inserte una contraseña: ")
lowercase = False
uppercase = False

for i in word:
    for a in range(len(letters)): 
        c = letters[a]
        if i == c.upper():
            uppercase = True
    if uppercase == True:
        break
else:
    print("Pon una mayúscula")

for i in word:
  for a in range(len(letters)): 
    if i in letters:
      lowercase = True
      break
  if lowercase == True:
    break
else:
    print("Pon una minuscula")
```

Sin embargo siempre dice que no hay ni minúsculas ni mayusculas, y no se porque

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en que haces lo siguiente:

```
letters   = string.ascii_lowercase
```

esto retorna una cadena con todas las letras ASCII:

```
>>> print(letters)
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Posteriormente haces:

```
letters   = letters.split()
```

Lo que retorna:

```
print(letters)
['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
```

Cuando recorres tu cadena `word` lo que haces es comparar cada carácter con `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` y `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`, por lo que te retorna `False` siempre.

Para pasar una cadena a una lista cuyos items son los caracteres del string basta con hacer:

```
>>> letters   = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> letters = list(letters)`
>>> print(letters)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

No obstante, no necesitas las listas, en python puedes iterar directamente sobre los caracteres de un string con un `for in` o usando índices. Simplemente crea tus strings e itera sobre ellos:

```
numbers = string.digits
letters   = string.ascii_lowercase
```

Para iterar sobre un iterable usa `for in`, no uses `range` + `indices` (a no ser que modifiques el iterable durante el ciclo). El primer método es mucho más legible, corto, "Pythónico" y además, es considerablemente más eficiente.

Por otro lado, puedes simplificar tu código usando generadores y `any`:

```
import string 

word = input("Inserte una contraseña: ")

if not any(c in string.ascii_uppercase for c in word):
    print("Ingrese una mayúscula.")
if not any(c in string.ascii_lowercase for c in word):
    print("Ingrese una minúscula.")
if not any(c in string.digits for c in word):
    print("Ingrese un número.")
```

O usar `str.isupper` y `str.islower`, y `str.sdigit`:

```
word = input("Inserte una contraseña: ")

if not any(c.isupper() for c in word):
    print("Ingrese una mayúscula.")
if not any(c.islower() for c in word):
    print("Ingrese una minúscula.")
if not any(c.isdigit() for c in word):
    print("Ingrese un número.")
```